# Issue with staplr package in R: set_fields returns the error 'Error: All unnamed arguments must be length 1'

Tags: r, installation, pdftools

I have been trying to generate a pdf file in R using the staplr package. However I have been running into issues whilst trying to run the example code. I keep getting an error (All unnamed arguments must be length 1) when trying to use the set_fields function.

```
library(staplr)
pdfFile = system.file('testForm.pdf',package = 'staplr')

# And do
fields = get_fields(pdfFile)
# You'll get a list of fields that the pdf contains 
# along with some additional information about the fields.

# You make modifications in any of the fields by
fields$TextField1$value = 'this is text'
set_fields(pdfFile, 'newFile.pdf', fields)

# This will create a filled pdf file
```

The get_fields function seems to work fine, I am using it in R and able to see that the field variable is updated with the new information. The issue is only when the set_fields function is applied.

I installed java using the code provided and installed rJava (install.packages("rJava")):

```
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install -y openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

I first installed the package in R using:

```
install.packages('staplr', dependencies = TRUE)
```

Uninstalled this version after is produced this error and tried:

```
devtools::install_github("pridiltal/staplr")
```

However the same issue keeps arising.

As part of my troubleshooting I tried to install pdftools using:

```
sudo apt-get install libpoppler-cpp-dev
```

I'm at a loss as to what to try next so any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

The set_fields function should output the pdf with the updated fields. As I am using the exampled code I assumed there was no issue with the structure but perhaps related to how the dependent packages were installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a DIFFERENT function of the R package staplr, and I do not have the problem anymore.

I discovered that this library uses the program PDFtk (https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

So, I installed the program (It seems that after you install the program you need to set the path environments in the operating system, at least for Windows. I noticed that you are using Linux) (If you want to watch a video about how to do set the path environment with Windows, check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=gb9e3m98avk&embeds_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2F&embeds_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com&feature=emb_logo) (If you want to know how to install PDFtk, check: https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/ ).

I also changed the R profile, or at least I believe that I did it, using the R command libpaths("folder where the R file and the PDF is located"). There are several questions about the R command libpaths in Stackoverflow, you can find them [in this link:](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow%20libpaths&rlz=1C1UEAD_enUS976US976&oq=stackoverflow%20libpaths&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.6601j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Before these changes, I was getting several errors, among them "normalizePath:."

All these tips worked in Windows, so you would have to adapt them because you are using Linux.

Comment: @JamesRisner Hey James! Thank you for your opinion! The ideas that I gave in my answer, most likely will solve the problem of this user, and the problems of others with this R library. I just wanted to share what helped me to solve a similar issue. In my perspective, the problem is not related to programming but to installation.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It seems I may have mistook this answer at first. Please update the answer to remove things like "Please let me know if you solved the problem ans how", things not relative like "I am learning Linux, and it would be great to know.", and since you reference a library it is always advised to show an example of the use of the library and not just link to it.

Comment: @JamesRisner Hey James! I updated my answer following your ideas. However, I cannot show code because, in my perspective, the problem is not the code, but the installation. Usually, an R package has all that is required, but in this particular case, in addition to the R package other installations and changes are needed. The details are in my answer. The code of the user was part of the documentation of the library. So, it is correct. The code of the question is from this link: https://rdrr.io/cran/staplr/man/set_fields.html